# Handling TOP in A CASE-WHEN select

Tags: sql-server

I am having a problem to resolve a SELECT CASE using TOP.

Should I mention I'm quite new to this ?

I want to fill one column of informations from two tables :

Table 1 : Column 1 contains data I want to use

Table 1 : Column 2 is a join

Table 2 : Column 1 contains data I want to use

Table 2 : Column 2 is a join

So :

Table 1 Column 1 contains letters (D M and T) and empty spaces.

Table 2 Column 1 contains words ('Rolls' 'Transfers' 'Delivery')

I'm trying to fill my column using the following conditions :

- When column T1.C1 contains D, M or T, write D M or T.
- When column T1.C1 is empty, look at column T2.C1 :

  - If column T1.C1 contains 'Rolls', write 'R'
  - Else don't write anything

Things get ugly really fast for me because the info I want from column B requires a TOP to be used.

THe best I could get so far is **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'**.

Here is my code so far. Any suggestions ?

```
SELECT (
    CASE T1.C1
        WHEN 'D' THEN 'D'
        WHEN 'M' THEN 'M'
        WHEN 'T' THEN 'T'
        WHEN (
            SELECT TOP 1 T2.C1 
            FROM T2 
            WHERE T1.C2=T2.C2
        ) LIKE 'ROLLS' THEN 'R'
       ELSE ''
    END) AS my_data
FROM T1
```

Comment: Be careful here. You are using TOP with no order by. There is no guarantee what order the subselect will use so you have no way of knowing what the top 1 is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `Case Statement` like this. You have mixed the `Input Expression` with `searched CASE expression`

```
SELECT ( CASE
           WHEN T1.C1 = 'D' THEN 'D'
           WHEN T1.C1 = 'M' THEN 'M'
           WHEN T1.C1 = 'T' THEN 'T'
           WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 T2.C1
                 FROM   T2
                 WHERE  T1.C2 = T2.C2) LIKE 'ROLLS' THEN 'R' -- (Add Order by Clause in Correlated Subquery)
           ELSE ''
         END ) AS my_data
FROM   T1
```

Comment: Kudos for your explanations. Works great. Thank you !

Comment: Be careful with the top and no order by. You should add an order by so you know which rows value you are getting.

Comment: @Adrien - Sean lange is right `Top 1` with out `Order by` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally clear from your question but I think you could simplify this and drop the sub query entirely.

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN LEFT(T1.C1 + T2.C1, 1) = 'R' THEN 'R'
    ELSE T1.C1
END AS MyData 
FROM T1
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work this afternoon. That's too bad, I really like your answer. I'll try again tomorrow. Thank you !

Comment: Did you get an error message? Did it not do the right thing? I can help but just saying it doesn't work doesn't give me the required info to help.